# Firebase - SnapShot - Can't acess array of elements, after snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a system that monitors users online with Snapshot. It evaluates any changes in the database and updates the front end, creating an array in  `this.players`.

The problem is that I can't access the array anywhere in the code. If I put `console.log(this.players)` the array appears, but if I try to access `this.players[0]` it returns "undefined".

I tried to create a global variable in the class, but I still can't access `jogadores`. I created a method that returns a promise, it worked, but strangely after 30 minutes, it stopped working.

```js
this.getDataFromFirestore = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("roleta")
      .doc(this.myId)
      .collection("jogadores")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
            const dadosDoJogador = change.doc.data();
            const nomeDoJogador = dadosDoJogador;
            this.jogadores.push(nomeDoJogador);
          }
          if (change.type === "modified") {
            // console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
          }
          if (change.type === "removed") {
            this.jogadores = this.jogadores.filter((v) => {
              return v.id != change.doc.data().id;
            });
          }
        });
        montarListaFront(this.jogadores, this.myId, this.myName);

      });


    resolve(this.jogadores);
  });
};

// Chamando a função que retorna a Promise
this.getDataFromFirestore().then((jogadores) => {
  console.log("funcionou xxxx");

  try {
    console.log(this.jogadores); // jogadores agora deve conter os dados atualizados
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("nao funcionou");
  }
});
```

Comment: You're passing `this.jogadores` in to the `then()` handler as the `jogadores` argument. As such you shouldn't use `this` to get the variable. Just use `console.log(jogadores)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so much *where* you access the `jogadores` array, but *when* you access it. The code inside `onSnapshot` runs asynchronously (as it needs to read the data from the network or from disk) and when you `resolve(this.jogadores)` the data hasn't been loaded yet.

You can most easily see this with some well-placed log statements:

```
console.log("Before starting onSnapshot");
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("roleta")
  .doc(this.myId)
  .collection("jogadores")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    console.log("Got data");
  });
console.log("After starting onSnapshot");
```

When you run this, the output is:

> Before starting onSnapshot
> After starting onSnapshot
> Got data

This is probably not the order you expected the data in, but it explains why your code doesn't work: you're resolving the promise before the array has been populated.

---

Since you are using a promise, the solution is to `get` the data rather than using `onSnapshot`. With that, you can simplify it to:

```
this.getDataFromFirestore = async () => {
    const snapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("roleta")
      .doc(this.myId)
      .collection("jogadores")
      .get();

    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        const dadosDoJogador = change.doc.data();
        const nomeDoJogador = dadosDoJogador;
        this.jogadores.push(nomeDoJogador);
      }
      if (change.type === "modified") {
        // console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === "removed") {
        this.jogadores = this.jogadores.filter((v) => {
          return v.id != change.doc.data().id;
        });
      }
    });
    montarListaFront(this.jogadores, this.myId, this.myName);

    return this.jogadores;
});
```

Also see:

- [Not able to iterate over array of users pulled from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477816/not-able-to-iterate-over-array-of-users-pulled-from-firebase/57478638#57478638)

Comment: Hi Frank, first of all, thany you for try to help. I trieds your code but keep the same problem. This problem is making me crazy.

Comment: First off, does the explanation in the first part of my answer make sense. And do you agree that this would/could explain the behavior you're seeing, and that the simplified code in my answer would/could fix that? ---

Only if "yes", it's hard to help with "keep the same problem". I recommend adding more logging to your code, similar to what I did in the first half to see the order of execution. Even if that doesn't help you to find the problem, it'll lead to a much better [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for posting in your question.

Comment: OK Frank, it is my first comment. I will make a better explanation of problem. But with your code, how can i acess this.jogadores[0] ? When i try this, return undefined.

Comment: I didn't change anything about that variable. You might want to run the code in a debugger. So: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you’re encountering issues with accessing the this.players array in your code. One possible reason for this could be the context in which this is being used. Arrow functions (() => {}) don’t bind their own this value but inherit it from the containing scope. However, there are exceptions, particularly when dealing with class methods and asynchronous operations.

Make sure this.myId and this.myName are properly initialized within your class as well. This structure ensures that this.players is accessed within the correct scope and should resolve the issue you’re facing.

Comment: I am analising this right now, i think you can be right, the problem i am new in programing, and i am with difficult to change all arrows functions.